# How do I redirect dynamic URLs with parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

The old URLs are like this:
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?mode=thread&id=284607

The new URLs would be:
http://mywebsite.com/threads/284607

As you can see, I want to grab the ID # from the old dynamic URLs and point them to the new pretty URLs.

I've tried finding the solution here and elsewhere, but keep having problems removing the "mode=thread" part from the redirect.

Thanks for your help!

Update: Here's some other code that is already in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of Googling, I found this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?)mode=thread&id=([0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://mywebsite.com/threads/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=thread
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /threads/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! It's now redirecting to: http://mywebsite.com/?mode=thread&id=284607

Comment: Yes, that's what you wanted isn't it?

Comment: I really, really appreciate your efforts. It's still just stripping the index.php out of the URL. I did look a little closer at the htaccess and realized that there are some other lines that might be causing some issues. I thought they were commented out previously. I've updated my initial question.

Comment: Where are you placing my answer in your htaccess file? Put it above the rules you already have.